# Unable to launch Debugging for a "npx" launched App in visual studio code

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, webdriver-io

I need to launch a particular .js file for execution, in this way:

1. `npx app.js launch.conf.js` //for execution of scripts
2. `npx app.js debug.conf.js` //for debugging the scripts

In my debug.conf.js contains

```
const config = {
  debug: true,
  execArgv: ['--inspect-brk'],
  maxInstances: 1,
  cucumberOpts: {
    timeout: 30 * 1000 * 4,
  },
};
exports.config =config
```

, When I Execute the 2nd command via CMD I'm able to debug using chromedev Tools debugger.
but when I need to debug using the VS code Editor:this is present in my launch.json file:

```
"type": "node",
"name": "manager",
"request": "launch",
"protocol": "auto",
//  "port": 5859,
"program": "${workspaceRoot}\\node_modules\\cdem\\bin\\app",
"execArgv": ["--inspect-brk"],
"args": [
    "run wdio.debug.conf.js"
]
```

I keep getting the console op as: debugger attached, waiting for debugger to disconnect and the execution is not launched.

Can someone let me how to debug this app using VS Code?

Comment: npx expects a module/bin as it's first argument. So, if you have jest installed as a module you can run `npx jest ...`. I don't think `npx app.js` makes sense.

Comment: Not sure if this one is still actual, WebdriverIO debugging docs were updated and there is an example VSCode config https://webdriver.io/docs/debugging.html#debugging-with-visual-studio-code-vscode

Does it resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

https://webdriver.io/docs/debugging provides details on how to run in VS code ([thank you Mike (comment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822088/unable-to-launch-debugging-for-a-npx-launched-app-in-visual-studio-code#comment113161979_50822088)):

1. Go to **Run and Debug** tab/blade (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>)
2. **Create a launch.json file** (e.g. type *Node.js* on environment bar) or click the cog at the top for other options
3. *.vscode/launch.json* opens up or locate and open it (from project's root folder)
4. Paste this in the **configurations** array, adjust according to your parameters/arguments and save the file:

   ```
    {
        "name": "run select spec",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        // To run all spec files remove "--spec", "${file}" from below
        "args": ["wdio.conf.js", "--spec", "${file}"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/@wdio/cli/bin/wdio.js",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "skipFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/**/*.js",
            "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js",
            "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
        ]
    },
   ```
5. Run the above by choosing this configuration (e.g. "run select spec") from the top left dropdown/select menu (or press <kbd>F5</kbd> if already selected).